# Visual studio 2012 portable class library and System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema refrence

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, silverlight

I use `visual studio 2012` and create `portable class library` for define my database domain.
when I use `class library` , can add `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` reference and can use `Foreignkey` , `Table` and `NotMapped` attribute to define my domain class. but when create `portable class library` I can't use this attribute and can't add above reference. 
I want to create `Silverlight` application and can't reference class library to it.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because `ForeignKeyAttribute` is only supported in .net 4.5 and not Portable Class Library. Check compatibility [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.aspx) (icons).

Because Silverlight is "going" to die, this will never be supported.

There were many addition in .net 4.5 and for [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) namespace, there are also unsupported *new* attributes in PCL.

Comment: so.How can define foreignkey in domain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EntityFramework fluent API approach for registering any of your POCO class/property attributes that are not supported in PCL. The other option is to use conventions in your naming of your POCO properties. More information can be found here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx